# In a flask function which returns `send_file`, the code doesn't appear to run on subsequent requests, yet the file still downloads. Why?

Tags: python, html, flask, href

I am using a Flask Code with the following route:

```
@app.route('/download')
def download_file():
    path = "certificate.docx"
    print("certificate printed")
    print(os.getcwd())
    return send_file(path, as_attachment=True)
```

HTML Code:

```
<p>
<a href="{{ url_for('.download_file') }}">Download</a>
</p>
```

This piece of code is being executed to download a file named `certificate.docx`.

The problem is that the print statements inside the function `download_file()` are not actually being executed, yet it still allows me to download the file.

Comment: debug your code and see if execution reach the print statement.

Comment: The print statements are not getting executed would mean that it isn't reaching there, but what doesn't make sense to me is how  then the docx file getting downloaded?

Comment: What command are you using to run the server?

Comment: at the moment, I am running it on local host, using `python file-name.py` @v25

Comment: And you're definately looking at the server console for the printed lines, and can't see `certificate printed` anywhere in there, when you click `Download`.  Perhaps can you edit the question with the server console output?

Comment: Yes! The file always gets downloaded! @v25

Comment: This sounds like it's down to caching, see my answer.

Comment: Could I know why my question got downvoted? I am ready to add additional information if necessary or modify the question in any manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is most likely caused by caching which is built into Flask.  This sets the `Cache-Control` header, and applies to static files served by Flask, but also the `send_file` and `send_from_directory` functions. [(reference)](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.get_send_file_max_age).

This would explain the behaviour of the file downloading, but the print statements not running.  In fact that request won't even be hitting the server.

You can visualise this on the network tab of the dev tools:

[image: caching enabled]

---

You can disable this by setting the following config variable on your app:

```
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = -1
```

The `-1` value disables caching.

You may have to actually clear the browser cache for this setting to take affect, or change the URL of your `/download` endpoint, although this is inconvenient.

Note the difference once this is set:

[image: caching disabled.]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried to add this line: `app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = -1`. Doing this is getting me the same result, the only difference being that now I am getting the response that my code is able to access the `/download` route. But I don't still see any of the print statements getting executed

Comment: I mean to say that my the file is still getting downloaded without the execution of the print statements

Comment: I would play around with this, and have the route `return 'some test string'` to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @SauravSaha OR Ensure the caching disable var is set to `-1`, change the decorator to `app.route('/download_ABC')` temporarilly, THEN restart the server and reload the template page and click the link to `/download_ABC`:  The print statements should run.  If they do, this would indicate that some kind of caching in the browser has that `/download` route cached.

Comment: Ok. Your solution works only if I change the name of my endpoint. But I can't just keep changing the name of my endpoint again and again.  Setting `app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = -1` doesn't seem to make a difference. I wonder if I am doing this in the correct manner. I am defining `app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = -1` below `app = Flask(__name__)`, this is what I should be doing right?

Comment: By the way, using the incognito window of my browser also solves the issue, the lines do get printed then.

Comment: @SauravSaha Yes, that's the correct place to define the config var.  The `Cache-Control` header is stored by the browser against a particlar URL, hence the reason for having to clear the browser cache prior to hitting an endpoint with a URL **you already hit** before setting that config var to `-1`.`  The default setting is 12 hours, so if you hit `/download` then tweak the config, further requests to `/download` from that browser will return the cached file for 12 hours, unless you clear the cache. Perhaps also look into CLI program `curl` which doesn't respect this header by default.

Comment: Ok! This does explain a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want the print statements to show in your HTML. I apologize if that is not what you are looking for.

First what print is doing in your example is outputting text on the server, so the text never is sent to your HTML.

To send messages to your HTML you can import `flash` from flask. The `flash` function will send a message to your HTML where you can receive code with `get_flashed_messages()`.

### Example

Here is an example adapted from the [Flask Docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/flashing/#message-flashing-pattern).

Below we do a few things.

1. Instead of `print`, we use `flash`. The first argument passed to `flash` is the message. (`"certificate printed"` or `os.getcwd()`) The second argument is the category of message. ( `"download_file"`) *Note that the category can be completely arbitrary as long as the same category is used in the template.*
2. Below the link in the HTML. We call `get_flashed_messages` and assign it to a variable `download_msgs`. The only argument in this case is `category_filter=["download_file"]`. This will get all the messages we sent with `flash` earlier and keep only the ones with the `"download_file"` category.
3. We check for messages with `{% if download_msgs %}`, loop over messages with `{% for message in download_msgs %}`, and display each message.

Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, send_file

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/download')
def download_file():
    path = "certificate.docx"
    flash("certificate printed", "download_file")
    flash(os.getcwd(), "download_file")
    return send_file(path, as_attachment=True)
```

HTML:

```
<p>
  <a href="{{ url_for('.download_file') }}">Download</a>

  {% with download_msgs = get_flashed_messages(category_filter=["download_file"]) %}
    {% if download_msgs %}
      <ul class=flashes>
      {% for message in download_msgs %}
        <li>{{ message }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% endif %}
  {% endwith %}
</p>
```

This example is crude, but I hope it answers your question

### Summary

- To send messages from your flask app to your HTML code, you can use the `flash` function in your flask app.
- To receive messages from your flask app to your HTML code, you can use the `get_flashed_messages` function in your HTML code.
- You can use categories to differentiate flashed messages. Use the second argument of `flash` in your flask app. Use the *category_filter* keyword argument of `get_flashed_messages` in your HTML code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your very well written answer, but it is not something that I actually need, the print statements have only been added as a substitute for some other lines of code that also aren't working when I am trying to access that route.