# Why does return jsonify() in flask goes to the API page instead of changing the page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to make an upvote/downvote system on my Flask website, and I am trying to implement it using AJAX so the page won't reload every time there is an upvote or a downvote.
My flask application for project is:

```
@main.route('/project',  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def project():
   ...

        return render_template('project.html', projects = all_projects, popular = liked_projects, recent = recent_projects,
        users = all_users, comments = all_comments, followed = followed_projects, joined = joined_projects, my = my_projects, projectMember = projectMember)
```

My flask application for the upvote button is:

```
@main.route('/projects/upvote/<int:id>')
def projectupvote(id):
    post = projectPosts.query.get_or_404(id)
    post.likes += 1
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({"likes":post.likes})
```

My HTML is:

```
<a href='/projects/upvote/{{project.id}}' class="votesButton">Up vote</a>
<a href='/projects/downvote/{{project.id}}' class="votesButton">Down vote</a>

<h1 style="margin-bottom:5%; display: inline-block;" id = 'likes'>&nbsp;{{project.likes}}</h1>
```

And my JS application is:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('a').on('click', function(event) {
  
      $.ajax({
        data : {
          likes : $('#likes').val(),
        },
        type : 'GET',
        url : '/project'
      })
      .done(function(data) {
  
        $('#likes').text(data.likes).show();
  
      });
  
      event.preventDefault();
  
    });
  
  });
```

When running the code, instead of updating the likes while staying on the page, it leads me to this:

[image: JSON API page]

It gives the correct data, but moves to another page displaying the raw JSON data of the likes.
Why does it happen and how to go about the situation? I have been researching for hours but couldn't get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Try moving `event.preventDefault();` before ajax call

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I just tried that, however it didn't change the outcome

Comment: Maybe then try specify data type in request parameters to JSON?
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: I second moving `event.preventDefaullt()` to before the ajax call. If this didn't solve it it could be due to Flask's built-in caching: which may be serving the old JS file, so your changes haven't taken effect.  [See this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61741672/2052575) which relates to CSS files, but will be relevant if you're serving static JS files in the same manner.